# Intellij: Maven compiler error reads GraalVM as version 20.0.1 even after updating to 23.0.0

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-2, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I'm trying to set up a development environment in Intellij IDEA with gluonfx to create native images but I keep getting an error during the build process.

[image: Error upon maven build (mvn gluonfx:build)]

I've updated GraalVM to version 23.0.0, but the compiler keeps reading that the version I have is 20.0.1

[image]

Error message returned -

> Error: Current GraalVM version (20.0.1) not supported.
> [ERROR] Please upgrade to 22.1 or higher

---

The current path I'm using is

> C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-community-openjdk-20.0.1+9.1

I've also tried using the install path within the graalvm directory, but then there's no java file for the program to find. Could there be something wrong with my POM file?

I'm not sure if I need to reinstall it or use a different path for it to work.

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyGluonApplication</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>20</javafx.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.18</gluonfx.plugin.version>
        <charm.version>6.2.3</charm.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.18</attach.version>
        <main.class>com.mycompany.sample.Main</main.class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>${charm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <graalvmHome>C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-community-openjdk-20.0.1+9.1</graalvmHome>
                    <mainClass>your.mainClass</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.19</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>

                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gluon-releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Use GluonFX plugin 1.0.19, and remove `graalvmHome`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I didn't have my main class declared in the right places

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>myapplication</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<name>MyGluonApplication</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>20</javafx.version>
    <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
    <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.18</gluonfx.plugin.version>
    <charm.version>6.2.3</charm.version>
    <attach.version>4.0.18</attach.version>
    <mainClass>com.mycompany.sample.Main</mainClass>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
        <version>${charm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>display</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>util</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.18</version>
            <configuration>
                <graalvmHome>C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-svm-java17-windows-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final</graalvmHome>
                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>native</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.19</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-native</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test-native</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>android</id>
        <properties>
            <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>ios</id>
        <properties>
            <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gluon-releases</id>
        <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```